# Silly Sally's Movie

Tags: cipher

My friend Sally and I love watching movies on Friday nights.
This week it's her turn to pick a movie.

> Sally: "I won't tell you the name of the movie but I will say this:
>   I love eating peanut butter and jelly sandwiches."
>
> Me: "But Sally, that doesn't help me!"
>
> Sally: "Here you go:
>   `(!,!)(#,%)(*,&)(#,!)($,!)(%,$)(*,^)(@,@)($,$)`"
>
> Me: "That's it?"
>
> Sally: "The key is simple..."

Did I mention Sally likes being mysterious?

**What movie did Sally choose?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> INCEPTION

First we note the symbols corrrespond to the

> Number keys on a US keyboard

giving us pairs

> (1,1)(3,5)(8,7)(3,1)(4,1)(5,4)(8,6)(2,2)(4,4)

The first element of each pair refers to

> The word in the phrase "I love eating peanut butter and jelly sandwiches"

The second element of each pair refers to

> The letter in that word

giving the answer.